# How to print array data following current date

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like the following:

```
$f= array("Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday", "Saturday");
```

I have run a foreach loop for $f and print date. Result is:

```
Array ( [0] => Sunday [1] => Monday [2] => Tuesday [3] => Wednesday [4] => Thursday [5] => Friday [6] => Saturday )
```

but I want if it is Wednesday today, then the output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => Wednesday [1] => Thursday [2] => Friday [3] => Saturday [4] => Sunday [5] => Monday [6] => Tuesday )
```

Here is my code:

```
$f= array("Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday", "Saturday");
foreach ($f as $value) {
    if($value == date('l')){
        $date[] = $value;
    }
}
print_r($date);
```

it return me the following result:

```
Array ( [0] => Thursday [1] => Thursday [2] => Thursday [3] => Thursday [4] => Thursday [5] => Thursday [6] => Thursday )
```

Comment: `date('l')` returns Thursday, because today is Thursday, and condition requires comparison operator, not assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by native php functions:

```
$i = array_search(date('l'), $f);
$date = array_merge(array_splice($f, $i), $f);
```

`array_search` finds today item in the array, `array_splice` removes tail of the array and returns it, `array_merge` combines that arrays in the proper order

**[demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/792064)**

Comment: Thanks for the solution @splash58

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!